# Any Integrated Mangement Tools out there? (DRAC, iLO, RAC)

Tags: remote-access, hp, remote, datacenter, drac

So I have been on the lookout for a master tool to manage all my Integrated management adapters on our servers here. Such as **Dell DRAC, HP Integrated Lights-out and IBM's RAC**

e.g [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/) works great for OS level access, RDP, VNC, SSH etc.. But is there such a tool to handle direct access to the Remote Console's, virtual media etc..

I know allot of Blade systems have this, but we are talking about 100's of servers ;)

Would like to hear your experiences in solving this problem and if any simple tools help, Third-party tools welcome but simple portable ones ;)

Comment: About 80% now ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at HP Systems Insight Manager and Dell's offering? What type of functionality are you seeking in a centralized management system? It appears that mRemoteNG can support the https and SSH connections needed to connect to your servers' DRAC, ILO and RAC controllers.

Comment: Insight Manager and Dell Open manager are great, but they are abit overkill for just remote access management. And aren't as portable as mRemoteNG. I have to work on my mRemoteNG configuration but wanted to see if the community use other tools out there.

Comment: SIM is the shit. It lets you manage the entire HP environment and *it's free.* You can rollout PSP, firmware, BIOS, and manage the iLOs. As well as put the list of them all in the same place. If you've got hundreds of HP servers and aren't using SIM, you're wasting so much of your time. I've not had a lot of experience with the Dell tools but I hear they aren't as nice. HP has a Dell add-on for SIM that I've not had much experience with either, but you should at least investigate it.

Comment: +1 for SIM - it's a beast!

Comment: +10 for SIM \o/

Comment: I have two simpleton question from this post. 1. How to use mRemoteNG to connect to IDRAC? 2. What is SIM as I did not find it on Google?